# Is random variable $X_i$ measurable on ${\mathcal F_{i+1}}$ or ${\mathcal F_{i-1}}$?

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let say I have a filtration $\mathcal F_i$ with $\mathcal F_1$ contained in $\mathcal F_2$, $\mathcal F_2$ contained in $\mathcal F_3$ and so on...$\mathcal F_n$. $X_i$ is a stochastic process, $X_i$ is measurable with $\mathcal F_i$ (adaptable). Is random variable $X_i$ also measurable on $\mathcal {F_{i+1}}$ or ${\mathcal F_{i-1}}$?

Comment: Please correct the fraction Fi+1/Fi-1 , what I mean is Fi or Fi-1, not a fraction. I don't think you can make a fraction of two sigma algebra.

Comment: Dear @Peter you can edit your post by pressing the edit below your question. I think you mean, $F_i$ is contained in $F_{i+1}$ i.e. $F_i \subset F_{i+1},$ right? if so, since $F_i$ contains $F_{i-1}$ and $X_i$ is $F_i$-measurable, then so is $F_{i-1}$-measurable, *not* necessarily $F_{i+1}$-measurable.

Comment: After thinking a little bit I think that's not the case for Xi is measurable on Fi-1, Xi is measurable on Fi, mean the set {w : X(w)< c} for every C belongs to Fi. Fi-1 is contained in Fi, which doesn't mean set {w : X(w)< c} contains in Fi-1.

Comment: I also think because Xi is Fi measurable, thus the set {w : X(w)< c} (for every c in R ) contains in Fi , and it must contains in Fi+1, thus making it Fi+1 measurable.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani The other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sigma(X_i)\subset\mathcal F_i\subset\mathcal F_{i+1}$, $X_i$ is certainly $\mathcal F_{i+1}$-measurable.

But in general $X_i$ is not necessarily $\mathcal F_{i-1}$ measurable: take $\mathcal F_i:=\sigma(X_k,1\leqslant k\leqslant i)$ where the $X_k$ are independent integrable non degenerated random variables. Then $\mathbb E(X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i-1})=\mathbb E(X_i)\neq X_i$.

It justifies the notion of predictable sequence/process.

Answer (score -1):

If $\mathcal{F}_i \subset \mathcal{F}_{i+1} \subset \mathcal{F}_{i+2}$ for $i = 1, 2, \ldots$, $X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_{i+1}$-measurable, but not $\mathcal{F}_{i-1}$-measurable.

[ incorrect statements removed. ]

Comment: "but E[Xi|Fi−1] is a random variable" I do not understand "is a random variable". Of course E[Xi|Fi−1] is a random variable, as is E[Xi|Fi+1].

Comment: Did: $\mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i+1}] = X_i$ is not a random variable, sinc $X_i$ is known.

Is $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_i] = X_i$ a random variable?

Comment: For **every** random variables U and V and sigma-algebra G, E[U|V] and E[U|G] are random variables. By definition. Always.

Comment: Did: I disagree; let me write it more precisely -- is $\mathbb{E}[X_i | X_i = x_i] = x_i$ a random variable?

Comment: ${\rm E}[X\mid Y=y]$ and ${\rm E}[X\mid Y]$ are two completely different objects. The first is a real number (for every $y$), the second is a random variable.

Comment: What @Stefan said. Additionally, when $P[Y=y]=0$, the quantity $E[X\mid Y=y]$ has no canonical definition... That is, unless one first defines correctly $E[X\mid Y]=u(Y)$, then one can choose to say that $E[X\mid Y=y]=u(y)$ for every $y$. But since $u$ is only almost surely unique, $E[X\mid Y=y]$ could be defined as $u(y)+42$ instead of $u(y)$, for infinitely many values of $y$.

Comment: Did: you wrote in the 1st comment that $\mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i+1}]$ is also a random variable, but I disagree.  $\mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i+1}] = x_i$ is a known constant, since we know the value of $X_i$ from $\mathcal{F}_{i+1}$.

Comment: @Wong : Thanks for help but I also disagree with your claim $\mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i+1}] = x_i$ , is a known constant, I think the conditional expectation is a random variable, one of its value maybe xi, but it can also have others value.

Comment: Peter: look at Shreve, vol. II, p. 66: "If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then the information in $\mathcal{G}$ is sufficient to determine the value of $X$."  In our case, since $X_i$ is $\mathcal{F}_{i+1}$-measurable, $\mathbb{E}[X_i | \mathcal{F}_{i+1}] = x_i$ is just a known constant.  Think of $i$ as time -- the expectation of Google's share price yesterday, given a filtration up to today, is a deterministic number.

Comment: @WilliamS.Wong Listen, I am not going to repeat it yet again many times but this is just plain wrong. Shreve's citation does not say what you think. The assertion that $E[X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i+1}]=x_i$ is not true (by the way, **for which $x_i$?**). In the present context, $E[X_i\mid\mathcal F_{i+1}]=X_i$. Please read carefully the definition of the conditional expectation of a random variable given another random variable or a sigma-algebra.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistakes.  I removed the erroneous part of the answer.